# Elementary proof Hilbert-Mumford stability criterion for $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, lie-groups, geometric-invariant-theory, stability

In [An elementary proof of the Hilbert-Mumford criterion](https://www.isibang.ac.in/%7Esury/hilbmumf.pdf), B. Sury gives an elementary proof of the Hilbert-Mumford **semi-stability** criterion for $G = \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ (and $G = \operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})$) acting linearly on a finite dimensional $\mathbb{C}$ vector space. To be more precise, the result he proves is (essentially) the following:

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional $\mathbb{C}$ vector space, $v \in V \backslash \{0\}$ and $G = \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ (or $G = \operatorname{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})$) seen as a Zariski-closed subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}(V))$. Then $0 \notin \overline{G.v}$ (closure in the Hermitian topology) if and only if forall one parameter subgroup $\varphi : \mathbb{C}^* \longrightarrow G$, we have $\mu(v,\varphi) \geq 0$ (where $\mu(v, \varphi)$ is the opposite of the smallest weight of the action of $\varphi$ on a non-zero component of $v$).

Let me first sketch the proof of Sury (which I find aesthetically appealing) and then ask my question. We proceed by double contraposition and proves that $0 \in \overline{G.v}$ if and only if there is a one parameter subgroup $\varphi : \mathbb{C}^* \longrightarrow G$ such that $\mu(v, \varphi) < 0$.

If there is a one parameter subgroup $\varphi : \mathbb{C}^* \longrightarrow G$ such that $\mu(v, \varphi) < 0$, then the various weights of the action of $\varphi$ on the components of $v$ are all strictly positive. As a consequence, $\lim_{t \rightarrow} \varphi(t).v = 0$ and finally $0 \in \overline{G.v}$.

The non trivial implication is the direct one. Assume that $0 \in \overline{G.v}$. I will deal with the case $G = \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$. The Cartan decomposition insures that $G = U(n) T_n U(n)$, where $U(n)$ is the group of unitary matrices and $T_n$ is the group of diagonal invertible matrices. Since $U(n)$ is a compact group, we have the equivalence:
$$0 \in \overline{G.v} \iff \exists w \in G.v, \ 0 \in \overline{T_n.w}.$$
So, up to dealing with $w$ instead of $v$, one can assume that $0 \in \overline{T_n}.v$. The group $T_n$ being a torus which acts linearly on $V$, its action on $V$ can be diagonalized, so that there exists $(m_{i,j}) \in \mathbb{Z}^{s \times n}$ such that:
$$\forall (t_1, \ldots, t_n) \in T_n, \ \operatorname{diag}(t_1, \ldots, t_n).v = \sum_{i=1}^{s} t_1^{m_{i,1}} \ldots t_n^{m_{i,n}} v_i,$$
where $v= \sum_{i=1}^{s} v_i$, $v_i \in V_i$ and $V = \bigoplus_{i=1}^{r}V_i$ is a decomposition of $V$ adapted to the action of $\varphi$. The hypothesis $0 \in \overline{T_n.v}$ easily (this is a small computation with sequences and limits) implies that there is no non-zero vector $(b_1, \ldots, b_s) \in \mathbb{R}^s$ with positive coordinates such that:
$$\forall j \in \{1,\ldots, n\}, \ \sum_{i=1}^{s} b_i m_{i,j} = 0.$$
The [Gordan Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1355578/what-is-the-intuition-behind-gordans-theorem) then implies that there exists $(a_1, \ldots, a_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that:
$$ \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, s\},  \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_j m_{i,j} > 0.$$
By density, one can choose $(a_1, \ldots, a_n) \in \mathbb{Q}^n$ and finally, up to scaling by a common denominator, $(a_1, \ldots, a_n) \in \mathbb{Z}^n$.
If one now considers the one-parameter subgroup $\varphi : \mathbb{C}^* \longrightarrow G$ defined by:
$$\forall t \in \mathbb{C}^*, \ \varphi(t).v = \operatorname{diag}(t^{a_1}, \ldots, t^{a_n}).v,$$
then one sees that $\mu(v, \varphi) < 0$, wich finishes the proof.

**Question** : is there a similar proof for the Hilbert-Mumford **stability** criterion? More precisely, I  would like to know if there is a similarly elementary proof of the implication:
$$ \textrm{forall one parameter subgroup $\varphi : \mathbb{C}^* \longrightarrow G, \ \mu(v, \varphi) > 0$} \implies \ \textrm{the orbit} \ G.v \ \textrm{is closed in $V$ for the Hermitian topology} $$

I have heard that some analysists use a version the Hilbert-Mumford **stability** criterion in infinite dimensional vector spaces. So I guess they don't prove it using the subtleties of proper algebraic maps as in the book *Geometric Invariant Theory* by Mumford, Fogarty and Kirwan. This lets me hope that there might be an elementary proof of the above-mentioned implication.